# Submit handler does not work

Tags: forms

I am trying to handle multiple submit buttons, but the handlers does not get called.

I am following http://www.hooksupport.com/blog/drupal-8-how-handle-multiple-submission-buttons-drupal-8-form, and this is the code I am using.

```
$form['add_field'] = array
    (
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Create field'),
      '#submit' => array('::create_field_submit'),
    );

 public function create_field_submit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
     drupal_set_message(t('Form Submitted Successfully'), 'status', TRUE);
}
```

The message I've trying to send does not appear. Why?

Comment: Is the first part of your code in the buildForm function ?

Comment: No, I want this to work with blockForm.. I thought it should work from there too.

Comment: I've recently been finding that the `'::foo'` approach doesn't always work. Try using `[$this, 'create_field_submit']` to at least rule that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is not working, then the reason for this is, that the block plugin is not the form class. This is `BlockForm`, which calls the methods in the plugin while building, validating and submitting the form. So if you want to add custom code to the submit in a block plugin override:

```
public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {}
```

This code will then be included when the form class calls `submitConfigurationForm()`.

If you have more than one submit button you can check the triggering element in `$form_state`.

---

Edit:

Another option is to use a static submit function instead of the class method.

Answer (score 0):

`'::create_field_submit'` doesn't mean *use the `create_field_submit()` method of the class containing the code I am using*. For [`FormState::prepareCallback()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AprepareCallback/8.4.x), the method handling such handlers, it means *Use the `create_field_submit()` method of the object returned from [`FormState::getFormObject()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AgetFormObject/8.4.x)*.

```
public function prepareCallback($callback) {
  if (is_string($callback) && substr($callback, 0, 2) == '::') {
    $callback = [$this->getFormObject(), substr($callback, 2)];
  }
  return $callback;
}
```

Given that `FormState::getFormObject()` declares its returned value to be an object implementing [`\Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AgetFormObject/8.4.x), this limits its possible usage to few classes, which doesn't include a block plugin, which doesn't implement that interface.

As Clive said, try with `[$this, 'create_field_submit']`, and see if it works.